Customize Clone Methods with AutoFixture
I have a problem with a unit test. I fill objects with AutoFixture and some of the objects have ICloneable objects somewhere in the hierarchy. The test is completely generic, so I need a solution that does not need to know concrete types in advance.
AutoFixture seem to generate some default implementation of ICloneable.Clone() methods which returns an object of type System.Object which then causes InvalidCastException in the code.
It is a common pattern to cast the return type of Clone to the declaring type in our codebase, so I need a generic customisation for AutoFixture that creates appropriate implementations for all ICloneable.Clone() methods found in the object hierarchy.
I had posted this question some time ago but it was closed because I provided no reproducable sample. But now here is:
[TestClass]
public class CloneMock
{
    public abstract class Foo : ICloneable
    {
        public abstract object Clone();
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public Foo Foo { get; set; }

        public void CloneTheFoo()
        {
            this.Foo = (Foo)this.Foo.Clone(); // this throws
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var f = new Fixture();
        f.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        var c = f.Create<Bar>();

        c.CloneTheFoo();
    }
}

This code leads to the following error:

System.InvalidCastException:
Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy' to type
'Foo'.
at Zeiss.Micro.LSM.Tests.Utilities.CloneMock.Bar.CloneTheFoo()


Quick observation. Your code works fine with the AutoNSubstituteCustomization so the first guess is that there is an issue in AutoMoqCustomization.

So the question is, can I customize AutoFixture to behave the way I want?

Quick workaround is to use this.Foo.Clone() as Foo instead of (Foo)this.Foo.Clone(). Passed for me. I'd consider it as a smell, the long way is already described by Mark ;)

As far as I can tell, the issue has nothing to do with the ICloneable interface as such. If you remove the interface declaration from Foo, the issue persists:
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract object Clone();
}

The problem is the poor API design afforded by the ICloneable interface. As is usually the case, attempting to write tests against an API highlights usage problems related to that API.
With AutoFixture one might attempt to address the issue by developing a custom ISpecimenBuilder that does the following:

Examining whether the request is for a PropertyInfo object.
If it is, examine if the property is writable.
If it is, examine if the property type declares an abstract Clone method that returns object.
If so, create a custom Mock<T> that correctly implements Clone.

While this doesn't sound so bad, you may soon run into various issues. For example, how do you implement Clone if the class in question has a private constructor, like the following?
public abstract class Bar : ICloneable
{
    private Bar()
    {
        // Do something important here.
    }

    public abstract object Clone();
}

Or what if the constructor requires multiple parameters, like the following?
public abstract class Baz : ICloneable
{
    private Baz(Qux qux, Quux quux, Quuz quuz)
    {
        // Do something important here.
    }

    public abstract object Clone();
}

The latter problem AutoMoq can probably help you resolve, but it gets complicated really quick. Consider other options.
Don't use ICloneable
While never explicitly deprecated, for decades ICloneable has been considered an interface better avoided.

"DO NOT implement ICloneable.
"DO NOT use ICloneable in public APIs."
- Framework Design Guidelines. Conventions, Idioms, And Patterns for Reusable .net Libraries, Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Abrams, Addison-Wesley, 2005, ch. 8.4, their capitalization.

The problem with this specific interface is that it's ill-defined, since the documentation

"does not specify whether the cloning operation performs a deep copy, a shallow copy, or something in between."
- ICloneable Interface, Microsoft documentation

Cwalina and Abrams (original .NET framework architects) instead suggest the following:

"CONSIDER defining the Clone method on types that need a cloning mechanism. Ensure that the documentation clearly states whether it is a deep or shallow copy."
- Framework Design Guidelines. Conventions, Idioms, And Patterns for Reusable .net Libraries, Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Abrams, Addison-Wesley, 2005, ch. 8.4, their capitalization.

For the example in the OP, that would entail a class like this:
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract Foo Clone();
}

If you make that change, the repro test passes.
I recommend a redesign of the code base that doesn't use ICloneable.
Legacy
That said, I haven't overlooked this piece of information:

"It is a common pattern to cast the return type of Clone to the declaring type in our codebase"

This could mean that you have a lot of code that does this. I understand that moving away from ICloneable may not be a viable solution, at least in the short term.
It is, however, the best solution I'll offer. If someone comes up with something better, you can just ignore this answer and upvote and accept the better one.

Yes, it is all about legacy code in our codebase which is following this pattern.
